# Why am I getting a "NameError: uninitialized constant" using has_many :through in Ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm a beginner to Ruby and have been trying to use a has_many :through association to join together 3 models. First, I have a Person model, a Subscription model and a SubscriptionDetail model.

Basically, a person can have many subscriptions through subscription details and, similarly, a subscription can have many people through subscription details. The models I used are:

In person.rb:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :institution
    has_many :subscription_details
    has_many :subscriptions, through: :subscription_details
end
```

In subscription.rb:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    has_many :subscription_details
    has_many :people, through: :subscription_details
end
```

In subscription_detail.rb :

```
class SubscriptionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :subscription
end
```

The relevant migrations are:

```
class CreatePeopleTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
        t.string :name, null:false
        t.string :email, null:false
        t.belongs_to :institution, index: true
        t.boolean :removed, :default => false
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSubscriptionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :subscriptions do |t|
        t.string :name, null:false
        t.belongs_to :product, index: true
    end
  end
end

class CreateSubscriptionDetailsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :subscription_details do |t|
        t.belongs_to :subscription, index:true
        t.belongs_to :person, index:true
        t.boolean :trial, :default => true
        t.string :mailing_preference, :default => "Cc"
        t.datetime :trial_start
        t.datetime :trial_end
    end
  end
end
```

When creating a person, I have a form set up to add multiple subscriptions to that person through the same form (using checkboxes) - I collect these into an array called "subscriptions". The subscriptions are created beforehand using another form. I use the following code (aslight modification on what's found in [has_many through additional attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363702/has-many-through-additional-attributes)) to create the person:

```
info = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    institution_id: institution.id
}

person = Person.create(info)
person.save

subscriptions.each do |each_subscription|
    person.subscription_details.create(
        :subscription => each_subscription,
        :trial_start => trial_start,
        :trial_end => trial_end
    )
end
```

But I always get the following error:

```
NameError at /institutions/1/add_person
uninitialized constant Person::SubscriptionDetail
```

**Update:** It throws the exception at the line that says `person.subscription_details.create(`.

When running the same code in console I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Person::SubscriptionDetail from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/li‌​b/active_record/inhe‌​ritance.rb:152:in 'compute_type'`

**Update 2:** I should note that when checking the databases in Postgres, it has created the person in the people table, but not the associated subscription details in the subscription_details table

I have checked the plurality of the model files, associations and even checked for typo's, tried using the :class_name attribute in the models, I tried it without `person.save` and spent the last 2 hours googling this, but I can't figure out why this is failing.

## Update

Form view (people/new.erb)

```
<form action="/institutions/<%= @institution.id %>/add_person" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="name">Name</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="person[name]" placeholder="Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="email">E-mail</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="person[email]" placeholder="E-mail"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="institution">Institution</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="institution" name="person[institution]" placeholder="<%= @institution.name %>" value="<%= @institution.name %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Subscriptions</th> 
            <td>
                <% @subscriptions.each do |subscription| %>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="person[subscriptions][]" value="<%= subscription.id %>"><%= subscription.name %></label><br>
                <% end %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="trial-start">Trial-start Date</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="trial-start" name="person[trial][start]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="trial-end">Trial-end Date</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="trial-end" name="person[trial][end]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add Person">
</form>
```

Comment: First: I don't know why you're getting that error. I'd be interested in how your routes are defined, how your models and controllers are namespaced, and how your forms are defined to start investigating. I mimicked your setup with the models and associations here and got things to work fine. Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`? I have more thoughts but not enough characters - can you include your forms, controller, and model code in your question? Then I might be able to take a stab at an answer.

Comment: @wendybeth wow, OK, clearly I'm more of a beginner that I thought - barely got what you said. What do you mean by how my models and controllers are namespaced? And I'm assuming form definition is just the structure of the form? And I have never heard of the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` things you speak of.
Also, my model code above is all there is and the bit about creating the person is from the controller - how much more of the code would you need?

Comment: Just a side comment, but Ruby/Rails convention would be for the local iterator variable to be called `subscription` rather than `each_subscription`. The variable represents a single subscription only, which changes with each iteration.

Comment: Not to worry. :) Your question is well-presented so I wouldn't worry too much. By namespaced: I saw you have 'institutions/1/add_person', so I'm wondering if you have your controllers set up 'app/controllers/institutions/people_controller' or not. Also, 'add_person' is not a default Rails route - normally that would be '/people/new' - so I want to see your config/routes.rb file. In the mean time, if you look into `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, I think you might find a lot of good stuff to help you out here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Also, by forms defined, I just mean the code in your view files that you're using to create the forms.

Comment: Again, @wendybeth , not sure I got you entirely, but here goes.
I've updated the question with my form views. About the namespace I have everything running through the institution_controller - this is because I wanted to pull the institution data from the URL and pre-fill the form with that info. So the URL format is something like "/institutions/institution.id/add_person". 

I haven't fully moved to using rails yet (I've frankensteined some rails together with Ruby), so I don't have a routes file, I just make them in the controller itself.

Comment: Which line exactly is throwing that exception? What happens when you replicate that code in the console?

Comment: @fylooi I get the saem error in console
`NameError: uninitialized constant Person::SubscriptionDetail
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:152:in 'compute_type' `
Also, sorry about not showing which line throws the exception, its the line that says `person.subscription_details.create(` - I've updated the question to show that.

Comment: Does `person.subscription_details` work in the console?

Comment: Do you have an attribute named `type` in either `Person` or `SubscriptionDetail`?

Comment: Running `person.subscription_details` gives the same NameError as before. Also, don't have any type attributes in either Person or SubscriptionDetail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now I feel really stupid. I apologize to everyone who would have wasted their time here and thank you sincerely for all the effort put in.

But this was my fault. I had forgotten to check my `config.ru` file. I fixed this issue by adding the following line to my config.ru file:

```
require './models/subscription_detail'
```

This is why my application couldn't see the SubscriptionDetail model. I'm just answering this in case it helps anybody who made the same mistake.

Thanks again to all the people who answered/commented.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.2, your SubscriptionDetails migration would look something like this:

```
class CreateSubscriptionDetailsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subscription_details do |t|
      t.belongs_to :subscription, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.belongs_to :person, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.boolean :trial, default: true
      t.string :mailing_preference, default: "Cc"
      t.datetime :trial_start
      t.datetime :trial_end
    end

    add_index :subscription_details, ["subscription_id", "person_id"], unique: true
  end
end
```

Not sure what changes have been made in 5.0, but it may be worth adding the index and foreign key constraints to see if it will fix the problem. You'll need to roll back the migrations and run them again, of course.